# Automate downloading embedded PDF files, using Python

Tags: python, url, pdf, download

I am writing a Python script to automate downloading some pdf pages (from public domain work) hosted at a website.
Unfortunately the individual pdf pages are embedded in frames, and when I used the following:

```
import time, urllib
for n in range(21,63):
    time.sleep(2)
    pdfPath="http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/imgsrv/download/pdf?id=wu.89038803698;orient=0;size=100;seq=%s;attachment=0"%(str(n))
    pdfName="Housner_"+str(n)+".pdf"
    f = open(pdfName, 'w')
    f.write(urllib.urlopen(pdfPath).read())
    f.close()
    time.sleep(2)
```

the files downlaoded were actually blank, and Adobe shows error, e.g. invalid image, embedded fonts etc. not found.

Can anyone kindly suggest me how to improve this script so that the PDFs downloaded are not errorneous/corrupt.

Thanks.

Comment: change 'w' to 'wb' because pdf files contain binary data.

Comment: Tons of thanks!! It worked (and special thanks for reminding that PDF for binary data, one has to use ´wb´ instead of ´w´.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `'w'` with `'wb'` in `open(pdfName, 'w')`

Answer (score 3):

You are writing binary information as if it were non-binary.

```
f = open(pdfName,'wb')
```

should do the trick.